# mongo .net driver generate wrong query

Tags: .net, mongodb

I want to use .net driver mongo to write a query which will check is property of elements of subcollection is equal to property of its owner. 
To make it clearer i will give an example

lets say we have @**personnel** collection with @**children**
and we wanna find any personnel that have same first name that his child

```
var query = db.GetCollection("personnels")
                .AsQueryable()
                .Select(person => person.Children.Any(child => child.FirstName == person.FirstName));
```

this query will be translated into

```
db.getCollection('personnels').aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "__fld0": {
                "$anyElementTrue": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$Children",
                        "as": "child",
                        "in": {
                            "$eq": [
                                "$$child.FirstName",
                                "$$child.FirstName"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "_id": 0
        }
    }
])
```

but there something goes wrong

instead of this "`$eq": [ "$$child.FirstName","$$child.FirstName" ],`

query should be translated into

```
"$eq": [ "$FirstName","$$child.FirstName" ]
```

Tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the FilterDefinitionBuilder type to query information. While LINQ is useful, I've found the more complicated queries kind of get messy using LINQ. Go to this link for more documentation. http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/driver/definitions/

Below would be an example on how to create a filter...

```
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq("x", 10) & builder.Lt("y", 20);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Forgot to mention, you will need the MongoDriver library... you can nuget the package into your project from the following command in the Package Manager Shell. Install-Package MongoDB.Driver